# document.getElementbyId in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to web development, and recently started making my own website. I am trying to add a navigation menu to my code, but according to the Chrome debugger the document.getElementbyId call is returning null. Can someone please tell me, why is it that the menu is not showing up. I have tried 4 different browsers. Here is the Javascript code :

```
document.getElementById("foot").innerHTML = "<p>&copy;"+ "All rights reserved. </p>";
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='Index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
"</ul>"; 

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='Index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Customers.html'>Data</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> My Website</title>
<link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>

    <div id = "main">

    <h2> Webpage</h2>


  <p>Pages (HTML)</p>
  <p>Style Sheets (CSS)</p>
  <p>Computer Code (JavaScript)</p>
  <p>Live Data (Files and Databases)</p>


    <footer id ="foot01"></footer>
    </div>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, you want to replace `document.getElementById("foot")` with `document.getElementById("foot01")` - the name doesn't match your HTML. Looks like [that's all you need](https://jsfiddle.net/d5pr4mnm/).

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("foot").innerHTML // you have mentioned Id as foot here
```

but it seems you have `<footer id ="foot01"></footer>`

**change either id to foot, or get element using the used id i.e foot01,** it will work

Fixed other problems after receiving comment

> Problems :
>
> 1. Missing charset
> 2. document was not loaded and your script was getting loaded before document could load fully

.

(Read about onload method in javascript) & how it varies from browser to browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title> My Website</title>
     <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script>

         function load() {
            document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML = "<p>&copy;"+ "All rights reserved. </p>";
            document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
                       "<ul id='menu'>" +
                       "<li><a href='Index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
                       "<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
                       "</ul>"; 

            document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
                       "<ul id='menu'>" +
                       "<li><a href='Index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
                       "<li><a href='Customers.html'>Data</a></li>" +
                       "<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
                       "</ul>";
          }
      </script
   </head>
   <body onload="load()">
       <nav id="nav01"></nav>
       <div id = "main">
          <h2> Webpage</h2>
          <p>Pages (HTML)</p>
          <p>Style Sheets (CSS)</p>
          <p>Computer Code (JavaScript)</p>
          <p>Live Data (Files and Databases)</p>
          <footer id="foot01"></footer>
       </div>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks it worked - but the menu was only visible in Google Chrome. Firefox and IE still  don't show up a navigation menu.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("foot")` won't find any matches, because there is no "foot" id. Instead, in your HTML code you use "foot01", so try with that!